# Terraform backward compatibility between 0.13.x to 0.12.x

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Hi Terraform techies ,

I have a problem statement here. I used Terraform 0.13.5 to create my infrastructure. Due to some of the constraints I need to move back to 0.12.18. when I have make changes in infrastructure ,I see that ,the state  files generated with tf 0.13.5 don't work with 0.12.8. is there a way I can backport the state files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a process, as far as I know there is not a shortcut. You will need to do a state migration which can be tedious depending on the size of the state file.

Another option would be to import the infrastructure into the 0.12 state, or use data sources instead of migrating.

Comment: That link to the documentation is about migrating state between versions of a provider and is for developers of Terraform providers rather than users. You would use it if you were storing state for a resource in one format and needed to move to another such as the underlying API of the target system changing and you wanting to align the resource configuration and its state to it.

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right, I removed the link.